# Handle Data Selection in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, element-plus

So, I am building a web application using Vue and element plus tables. In it the user can upload multiple tables select data (handled by `@selection-change`) and create graph of that data (using v-network-graph).

```
<el-table v-for="(tab,index) in r" :data="tab" :key="index"  border style="width: 100%" height="500" @selection-change="handleSelectionChange" @header-click="contextmenu">
  <el-table-column type="selection" width="55"/>
  <el-table-column  fixed align="center"  v-for="col in x[index]" :prop="col.field" :label="col.field" :key="col.field">
  <template #header="scope" > 
        <el-menu
          :default-active="activeIndex"
          class="el-menu-demo"
          mode="horizontal"
          @select="handleSelect">
          <el-sub-menu index="1">
            <template #title>{{col.field}}</template>
            <el-menu-item index="Source" @click="handleSource(scope.column.property)">Source</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="Target" @click="handleTarget(scope.column.property)">Target</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="Using" @click="handleUsing(scope.column.property)">Using</el-menu-item>
            <el-sub-menu index="Property">
              <template #title>Property</template>
              <el-menu-item index="Property_target" @click="handlePropertyTarget(scope.column.property)">Target</el-menu-item>
              <el-menu-item index="Property_target" @click="handlePropertySource(scope.column.property)">Source</el-menu-item>  
              </el-sub-menu>
            </el-sub-menu>
        </el-menu>
      </template>  
      </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column>
    <template #header>
        <el-input v-model="searchQuery" size="small" placeholder="Type to search" />
      </template>
      <template #default="scope">
        <el-button size="small" type="danger" @click="handleDelete(scope.$index,index)">Delete</el-button>
         <!--<el-button type="primary" @click="handleEditRow(scope.$index)">Edit</el-button>-->
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  
  </el-table>
```

I am stuck on how I can handle the selection of data in these tables.
To be specific, when a user selects a row element plus tables have an event which adds that selected row to an array
[selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhte.png)

[array made by element plus table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZOmw.png)

Now when I select a row in another table
[row selected in another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeDlW.png)

[new array made by element plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJBSg.png)

Now since element plus makes different arrays for different table, I thought of pushing the data selected into a different array, which can store the data selected from both tables [Array that stores combined data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpk43.png).

```
handleSelectionChange(val){                //WHAT LOGIC CAN I USE
  console.log(val)
  for(let i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    if (Object.values(this.selected_data).includes(val[i])==false){
    this.selected_data[Object.keys(this.selected_data).length] = val[i]
  }
  }
   console.log(this.selected_data)
 }
```

Now when I remove a selected row from a table the element plus array removes it from the array that it creates, but how can I remove it from the array that I created so that when a user removes a row and creates the graph again that removed row shouldn't come up in the graph.
[Row unselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze6V8.png)

[array updated by element plus and my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffP2s.png)

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I'll be grateful if anyone can give me a hint of the logic I should use or if someone has experience in this can let me know how I can tackle this problem.